# MAUI Failed Package installation [ workload restore ]

Tags: .net, maui

[image]Downloading Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk.Msi.x64 (7.0.14)
Workload installation failed. Rolling back installed packs...
Workload installation failed: One or more errors occurred. (Failed to validate package signing.

Verifying Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk.Msi.x64.7.0.14

Signature type: Author
Subject Name: CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
SHA256 hash: 566A31882BE208BE4422F7CFD66ED09F5D4524A5994F50CCC8B05EC0528C1353
Valid from: 7/27/2023 3:00:00 AM to 10/18/2026 2:59:59 AM

Signature type: Repository
Subject Name: CN=NuGet.org Repository by Microsoft, O=NuGet.org Repository by Microsoft, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
SHA256 hash: 5A2901D6ADA3D18260B9C6DFE2133C95D74B9EEF6AE0E5DC334C8454D1477DF4
Valid from: 2/16/2021 2:00:00 AM to 5/16/2024 2:59:59 AM

)

I try to install dotnet workload restore
and it depend on Micrsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk.Msi.ox64 (7.0.14)
and I want to disable Verifying or re-install
Micrsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk.Msi.ox64 (7.0.14)

Comment: You can refer to this similar issue : [Fail to install MAUI from main branch with error "Package signature validation failed"](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9573).